# jquery slider not working as requirement in html page

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am coding a website ,having next and previous button for next page using slide method ,
i am able to do next slide on click event of next button but when i try to put action for previous button then its create problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Telas</title>
<!---------------------------------------Script---------------------------------------->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="Text/javascript">
        $(document).ready("#BtnNext").click(function () {
            if ($('#MainContainer').css("marginLeft") == "-4275px")
             {
                $('#MainContainer').css("margin-left", "+1425px");
            }
            $('#MainContainer').animate({ marginLeft: "-=1425px" });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready("#BtnPrev").click(function () 
        {
            $('#MainContainer').animate({ marginLeft: "+=1425px" });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="Layout">
            <div id="Header"></div>
            <div id="ButtonBar">
                    <input id="BtnNext" type="button"  />
                    <input id="BtnPrev" type="button"  />
                </div>
            <div id="MainContainer">
            </div>
            <div id="Footer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define: 'create problem'...

Comment: its not working as requirement even next button also not working correctly

Comment: As an aside, Why are you calling document ready twice ? Just do it once and set both events?

Comment: can you edit my code.i am trying but new in jquery so creating  problem